# sqlalchemy filters and sql injection

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm accepting a GET query parameter which will be used as piece of a search string.

If I have this:

```
x = request.args['x']
MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.myCol.ilike(x)).one()
```

Am I vulnerable to a SQL injection attack?

EDIT - I am using Postgres and SQLAlchemy 1.0 I think.

Comment: Which version of SQLAlchemy are you using? And with which database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy + SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501583/sqlalchemy-sql-injection)

Comment: It is not a duplicate IMO. The accepted answer there might be wrong in that it quotes a non-authoritative source. That question is also not about filter() specifically.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31949750/3359014,

`MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.myCol.ilike(x)).one()` is not considered a raw sql and the underlying db-api will escape x.