# SQLAlchemy: Dynamically pass schema and table name avoiding SQL Injection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I execute an SQL query where the schema and table name are passed in a function? Something like below?

```
def get(engine, schema: str, table: str):
    query = text("select * from :schema.:table")

    result = engine.connect().execute(query, schema=schema, table=table)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here:

1. Avoiding SQL injection
2. Dynamically setting a schema with (presumably) PostgreSQL

The first question has a very broad scope, you might want to look at older questions about SQLAlchemy and SQL Injection like this one [SQLAlchemy + SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501583/sqlalchemy-sql-injection)

Your second question can be addressed in a number of ways, though I would recommend the following approach from SQLAlchemy's documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#remote-schema-table-introspection-and-postgresql-search-path

PostgreSQL supports a "search path" command which sets the schema for all operations in the transaction.

So your query code might look like:

```
qry_str = f"SET search_path TO {schema}";
```

Alternatively, if you use an SQLAlchemy declarative approach, you can use a MetaData object like in this question/answer [SQLAlchemy support of Postgres Schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298296/sqlalchemy-support-of-postgres-schemas)

Comment: `qry_str = f"SET search_path TO {schema}";` allows SQL injection, though.